# How to stop loading the page using knockout js after the event has completed in magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am adding the custom price to order total, its fine adding the price.but the page loading is still loading, how can i stop loading using knockout js.
Thanks in advance

i have this code in my knockout file js

```
 return storage.delete(
                url,
                false
            ).done(
                function () {
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    isApplied();
                    totals.isLoading(true);
                    getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                    $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                        totals.isLoading(false);
                        isLoading(false);
                    });
                    messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                        'message': message
                    });
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    isLoading(false);
                    totals.isLoading(false);
                    errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
                }
            ).always(
                function () {
                    isLoading(false);
                }
            );
```

Comment: Please add your code lines.

Comment: I have add my code please check @KhoaTruongDinh